# Magento 2.1.1 How to load Order with Increment ID using OrderRepository object

Tags: magento2, module, orders, magento-2.1

What would be **the latest best practice to load Order using increment ID** (instead of Order ID) using **OrderRepository**

Comment: **Not a duplicate** - the linked answer is about retrieving the order by order id, not by increment id

Comment: ekk! Is there a way to undo the mark as duplicate? I meant to mark the answer below as the answer to the solution.

Comment: Too late, now that it is already closed. But I nominated the question to be reopened.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Magento 2 uses Service Contracts for retrieving and saving objects. In Magento this layer is formed by Repositories, which are managers with `get()` and `save()` methods. This keeps user code away from Model calls. Don't call model methods (like `load()` or `save()` or `loadByIncrementId()`) directly, they are being deprecated as custom code should use the Service Contracts. Also, don't use the API from within Magento like Khoa is suggesting, it does not make sense. The API is for connecting Magento with other systems.

Inject OrderRepository and SearchCriteriaBuilder in your constructor:

```
private $orderRepository;
private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
){
$this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
parent::__construct($context);
}
```

And in your function:

```
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
    ->addFilter('increment_id', '000000001', 'eq')->create();
$orderList = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();

// $orderList is now an array of Orders with this incrementId, which is just one order obviously

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
$order = reset($orderList);
// Your logic here
$order = $this->orderRepository->save($order);
```

[Official Magento PHP Developer guide on magento.com](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html)

[Code by Mulderea on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3534#issuecomment-227413082)

Comment: I am getting error like : Cannot use object of type Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection as array at $order = $orderList[0];

Comment: That's odd, I got an array. Which version are you on? But with a collection you can just replace `$order = $orderList[0]` with `$order = $orderList->getFirstItem()` to get the first (and only) item from the collection.

Comment: I am in version 2.1.3. and I need to load order object for load payment object .. I have done `$order = $orderList->getFirstItem();
$payment = $order->getPayment();`
But getting nothing in `$payment`

Please check my problem here
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158935/magento-2-unable-to-set-payment-transaction-id-after-successful-payment-process

Comment: I had a bug with the accepted answer. This solved it. Thanks for the good solution

Comment: In Magento 2.3.x I need to get the order this way: `$order = $orderList['000000001'];`

Comment: @ph.dev `$order = end($orderList)` would be better since `'000000001'` here is order ID which you probably don't know.

Comment: @KrzysztofWołowski Upvote and you are right. `$order = reset($orderList)` could be used too, and maybe more semantic.

Answer (score 22):

As far as I know, we should use `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface`.

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory $order **/

protected $orderFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory $orderFactory,
    ......
) {
    $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;

}
```

Load order object by increment id:

```
$this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId('00001952-42');
```

**[EDIT]** should try with service contracts. Try Jacco's answer.

Comment: Please don't use underscores in your variable names. PHP has had access modifiers since PHP 5, which is now 12 years old. You should use modern programming practices, especially in answers here.

Comment: @JaccoAmersfoort Thanks your input. However, I also took a look your answer below. I need to check and confirm.

Comment: this is not working in my controller... please suggest why?

Comment: @AshishRaj you can show me your controller? You should open new question. I will take a look.

Comment: yes but its little big in lines... so will not come inside the comment box... but i m doing the same thing .. loading as above in constructor and using as like `$order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId('00001952-42');` and then doing `$payment = $order->getPayment();` But getting nothing in `$payment` Please check my problem here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158935/magento-2-unable-to-set-payment-transaction-id-after-successful-payment-process

Comment: @AshishRaj Okay! I'm checking your question.

Comment: This method should not be used even if it "works".  One: the di injection is a shared object unless it is specified to not be; anytime you insert OrderInterface in you'll be using the exact same object.  If you really want to go this route use OrderInterfaceFactory and then call create(). Second, you should be using the service contracts as in Jacco's answer.

Comment: @Ian I agreed with you that we should use service contracts. I also voted up Jacco's answer.

Comment: version 2.2.2, use `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` and its `get()` method

Comment: service contracts must be taken in consideration.

Comment: @ThiagoLima yes, I agreed with you! I also voted the service contracts answer.