# Magento 2: unable to set payment Transaction Id after successful payment processing (solved by myself)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, payment, magento-2.1.3

I am unable to set payment transaction id after successful payment processing...

I have got payment confirmation transaction details by payment gateway on my controller action. Now I need to save the payment transaction id in `\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment` 
by using `setTransactionId` method of above interface.

But unable to use the `\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface`

Using code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$payment = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface');
$payment->setTransactionId(htmlentities($transaction_result->id))
                ->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
```

Getting error as: Cannot instantiate interface `Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface`

Please suggest way to get payment instance for save/update order transaction in custom method of model.

I am in return url page of payment

As I have redirected  payment gateways after payment done or failed at payment on a controller action.

On the url's at controller, I need to get current order/payment and then update truncation id to that order/payment object.

I have just tried below solution:

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
   ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    .....
) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

 public function execute(){
    $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $payment->setTransactionId(htmlentities($transaction_result->id));
    $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
            ->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                    "some text",
                    htmlentities($transaction_result->id)
                );    
}
```

But `$this->_checkoutSession` comes with empty array...
It means after coming back from payment gateway session get flushed... but how and why.. then how to get order object?

I have got order Increment id... Now how to get order object with order increment id?

I have also used below links:

[Magento 2.1.1 How to load Order with Increment ID using OrderRepository object](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140374/magento-2-1-1-how-to-load-order-with-increment-id-using-orderrepository-object)

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3534#issuecomment-227413082

for get order object by order increment id but don't found order object yet for get payment object.

**Update:**

When i am coming back from payment gateway as redirect url on my module controller execute function i am not getting object manager or session object or order object... I dont know much about dependency injection... please elaborate if i have to create and put any code in the di file in etc folder...

below code are not working in my module controller execute function:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$payment = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface');
```

It return null/empty

And if I am using below  code:

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
   ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    .....
) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

 public function execute(){
    $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $payment->setTransactionId(htmlentities($transaction_result->id));
    $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
            ->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                    "some text",
                    htmlentities($transaction_result->id)
                );    
}
```

then this also not working...

Please help to resolve the issue...

Comment: You can read Magento payment dev guide, it describes how you can use response handler to store transaction details http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/response-handler.html

Comment: I need payment object  in return url page controller action of payment

Comment: You should not write any logic in controllers, they should be 'thin', you can call some service or gateway command instead and process all logic in response handlers.

Comment: yes I try to call my model function of my module but getting same problem .. need payment/order object/instance for save transaction id ...

Comment: @AshishRaj, You can try with $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId(); to get order id instead of getLastRealOrder();

Comment: I have the order incremented Id which i had pass to payment gateway and they giving me in response... What i need is a order object... for save payment transaction id in order... please help

Comment: Try with, public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
$order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId());

Comment: $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($this->_ch‌​eckoutSession->getLa‌​stRealOrderId()); is returning null... i am not able to create order object in my controller while coming back from payment gateway as return url... infact... not even order object but session object is also coming empty ... dont know why...

Comment: You cant get last order id in controller after order placed because after place order checkout session is flushed out. so you cant get last order id from checkout session

Comment: I have the order id and transaction id and order is just placessed but not finished... i am just get back from payment gateway and want to save order id and transaction id in order respectively... I need to get order object with my order id which i have already... but unable to get or create object in my controller action of redirect url of my payment gateway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to save/update payment gateway transaction id in my order while coming back from payment gateway after successful payment but was getting in return url controller action..

I have solved my problem by adding another method in payment model and save transaction id with respect to order id in db and get that in capture method of payment model....

As I was unable to create/get object manger and session data variable in my controller and was unable to get transaction id in capture function of payment module which is already extending `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc`
because of use of curl.

Transaction id is coming on redirect url controller action and then we are coming after curl excution line of code where i was needed to save transaction id in the order and payment.

As I am using CURL method in my payment capture function for call payment gateway and passing order id and order detail to payment gateway with a return url. 
Payment gateway successfully coming back on the return url controller action. 
So I call my payment model new function `captureNew` and pass transaction detail as a argument. 
Then go in payment module `captureNew` function and save transaction id with order id in a database custom table and after the execution of captureNew function...

Then it return back in capture method under the curl execution line and there I get the transaction id by the order id from db and save in the order and payment object by  below code

```
$payment->setParentTransactionId(null);
$payment->setTransactionId($order_transactionId)->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, **$payment** object should be taken from `order object.`

So. You need change

```
$payment = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface');
```

to

```
  $payment = $orderObject->getPayment();
  $payment->setTransactionId(htmlentities($transaction_result->id));
        $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
          ->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                            "some text",
                            htmlentities($transaction_result->id)
                        );
```

### Modify code in return url page of payment

As you have *redirect to our customer  at payment gateways* then 
there should ***be a page  in magento*** where our customer ***will be  redirect after payment done or failed at payment***.

On **that url's at controller**, you need to get **current  order** from checkout session `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` .then you need to update ***truncation id*** to that order object.

At controller class. You need inject *some class from which you can get Order object* **\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session**

```
protected $_checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
   ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    .....
) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

 public function execute(){
    $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $payment->setTransactionId(htmlentities($transaction_result->id));
    $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
            ->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                    "some text",
                    htmlentities($transaction_result->id)
                );    
}
```

Comment: where you have write the code?

Comment: in class Payment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc it is my model for my custom payment method integration...

Comment: I need ur  payment gateway success page controller

Comment: I am simply using public function execute() {} method of my controller... for get payment gateway transaction redirect with transaction details

Comment: going you the code...

Comment: getting error as: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setTransactionId() on null in my execute function ... please help me ...

Comment: getting empty $this->_checkoutSession.. I mean Checkout session shows empty in my controller... so what i should do.. please suggest...

Comment: please help amit...

Comment: Hi Amit please help...

Comment: i can help at night.. busy on some project

Comment: Hi Ashish Raj , can u please tell  which payment gateways.. you have  using? What is return url of ur payment gateways?

Comment: yes... I am using custom braintree payment gateway... and redirect url is my index controller of my module...

Answer (score 2):

You need to put below code in the success action of your code when responce came after successfull payment.

```
$order = $this->getOrder();
$payment = $order->getPayment();

$trans_id = 'Transection id returned from Brantree Payment';            
$payment->setLastTransId($trans_id);
$payment->setTransactionId($trans_id);
$payment->setAdditionalInformation(
      [\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::RAW_DETAILS => (array)$payment->getAdditionalInformation()]
);
$formatedPrice = $order->getBaseCurrency()->formatTxt(
                $order->getGrandTotal()
            );

$message = __('The Captured amount is %1.', $formatedPrice);
//get the object of builder class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction\Builder
$trans = $this->_transactionBuilder;
$transaction = $trans->setPayment($payment)
->setOrder($order)
            ->setTransactionId($trans_id)
            ->setAdditionalInformation(
                [\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::RAW_DETAILS => (array)$payment->getAdditionalInformation()]
            )
            ->setFailSafe(true)
            //build method creates the transaction and returns the object
            ->build(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::TYPE_CAPTURE);

            $payment->addTransactionCommentsToOrder(
                $transaction,
                $message
            );
            $payment->setParentTransactionId(null);

            $payment->save();
            $order->save();
            $transaction->save();
```

Thanks

Comment: i was unable to get transaction id in capture method of payment model but was getting in return url controller action.. I have solved my problem by adding another method in payment model and save transaction id with respect to order id in db and get that in capture method of payment model...

Thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but this only happens when I try to generate invoices in Loop. The first transaction creates an invoice & transaction in DB but when I attempt to capture payment ( ONLINE ) in the loop for second order, the system generates invoices correctly. Still, when I save the order to Generate a Capture Transaction in Db, the system gives me an error.

```
{"error":"Set order for existing transactions not allowed"}

private function processNewInvoice(Order $order, array $items, $amount, $pendingInvoice, $id): Invoice|bool
{
    try {
        $this->_logger->info('Invoice Creation', ['invoice' => $pendingInvoice . '-' . $order->getEntityId()]);

        $newInvoice = $order->prepareInvoice($items);

        $newInvoice->setGrandTotal($amount);

        $newInvoice->setData('ora_invoice_number', $pendingInvoice);

        $newInvoice->setBaseGrandTotal($amount);

        $this->_logger->info('Invoice to be processed', ['invoice' => $newInvoice->getData()]);

        if (!$newInvoice->getTotalQty()) {
            $this->_logger->debug('Cannot create an invoice without products for order ' . $order->getIncrementId());
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Cannot create an invoice without products'));
        }

        $newInvoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);

        $newInvoice->register();

        $newInvoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

        $newInvoice->save();

        //Create Transaction
        $transaction = $this->transactionFactory->create()
            ->addObject($newInvoice)
            ->addObject($order);
        $transaction->save();

        $comment = 'Amount of $' . number_format($newInvoice->getGrandTotal(), 2) . '. Transaction ID: "' . $newInvoice->getTransactionId() . '"';
        $order->addCommentToStatusHistory($comment)->save();

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $this->_logger->critical('Cannot create invoice', ['error' => $exception->getMessage()]);
    }

    $this->_logger->info('Invoice Saved and captured', ['invoice' => $newInvoice->getId()]);

    return $newInvoice;
}
```