# Fetch a specific model in magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, factory

I have 2 ways to fetch a model object:

```
$orderId = 18;
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $firstOrder */
$firstOrder = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load( $orderId);

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection $orderCollection */
$orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
$secondOrder = $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $orderId)->getFirstItem();

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection $orderCollection */
$orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();
$thirdOrder = $orderCollection->addFilter('entity_id', $orderId)->getFirstItem();
```

The first one is using **load()** method of model object.

The 2 last one use **collection** to fetch and then get the first item of those collections.

I know **load()** is deprecated, but as I can see Magento 2 core modules use it a lot.

Somebody, please tell me what option is better?

And by the way, what is the diffirent between **addFilter()** and **addFieldToFilter()**.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use Service contracts:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html

For example:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155341/33057

Comment: Khoa, Thank you for your answer!
Yeah. there is a way using service contracts, but why the core codes of magento 2 aways use load(), filter() and addToFilter() method ?