# How to get image and price in shipping email template in Magento2.3?

Tags: magento2, shipping, email-templates

How to get product image and price in shipping email template.[image]

For image i add a code in shipping/default.phtml

```
<?php
$productId = $_item->getProductId();
$objectManagerHere = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManagerHere->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productImage = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($product, 'category_page_list')->getUrl();
?>

<td>
    <img height="80" width="80" src="<?= $productImage ?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
</td>
```

but i get's only placeholder image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $imageHelper  = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
  $image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
  $priceHelper = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); 
  echo $priceHelper->currency($product->getFinalPrice(), true, false);
```

It's will be helpfull

Comment: Hi, @arun I place your code, still image  get's placeholder image and price set as "0.00"

Comment: Thank you @Arun, i listed image, but for my swatch products, it listed only parent image, i like ti get my selected child image.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174758/magento-2-get-child-product-image-thumbnail?answertab=votes#tab-top . this link may be helpful mohana

Comment: Thanks for you link, let me check and for shipping email , not getting price. Please let me know. - Arun

Comment: Now getting the image working fine and getting a price is only your problem right?

Comment: Hi, @arun now i'm getting price . Thank you.Only need to get child image in my shipping email template

Comment: Hi mohana .are you need to get child image or small image of simple product

Comment: Need to get child image in my swatch product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91347/discussion-between-arunprabakaran-m-and-mohana).

Comment: Hi, I had an error in this. Can you please help me now?