# Magento 2 getMediaGalleryImages() return null

Tags: magento2, product-images, media

I am writing an import product job on Magento 2. I want to delete all product images if I need to update the product. I try to use `$product->getMediaGalleryImages()` to get all the images from the product but it returns null after running. I ensure that the product has an image. Follows is the code I tried.

```
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product = $product->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect("*")->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'sku-01')->getFirstItem();
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages(); // it return null
```

And follows is the code to upload product image.

```
$product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))
                            ->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the product media gallery images as given below.

**Method 1:** Use dependency. **(Recommended)**

Create a helper

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler as GalleryReadHandler;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $galleryReadHandler;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        GalleryReadHandler $galleryReadHandler
    )
    {
        $this->galleryReadHandler = $galleryReadHandler;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /** Add image gallery to $product */
    public function addGallery($product) {
        $this->galleryReadHandler->execute($product);
    }

}
```

Now add code to your phtml file as below.

```
$_helperGallery = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');
$_helperGallery->addGallery($product);
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach ($images as $image) {
    print_r($image->getData());
}
```

**Method 2:** Use objectManager directly in your phtml file. **(Not Recommended)**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler")->execute($product);
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach ($images as $image) {
    print_r($image->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
/* Add media gallery data to loaded items
 * @since 101.0.1
 * addMediaGalleryData()
 */
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product = $product->getCollection()
->addFieldToSelect("*")
->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'sku-01')
->addMediaGalleryData()
->getFirstItem();
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

Try to add **addMediaGalleryData()** to your collection. Without it, getMediaGalleryImages() will always return null

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may be with this code

```
$product = $product->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect("*")->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'sku-01')->getFirstItem();
```

Try below code instead

```
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product = $product->loadByAttribute('sku', 'sku-01');
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

**Note:-**  you should not use object manager directly instead use `ProductRepository` check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/111248/20064) for proper Magento 2 way to load product