# get product id from item id in magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

**I am trying to retrive product id from item id.**

i created first js function in **sidebar.js:**

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
'underscore',
'jquery/ui',
'mage/decorate',
'mage/collapsible',
'mage/cookies'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm, _) {
'use strict';

$.widget('mage.sidebar', {
    options: {
        isRecursive: true,
        minicart: {
            maxItemsVisible: 3
        }
    },
    scrollHeight: 0,
    shoppingCartUrl: window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,

    /**
     * Create sidebar.
     * @private
     */
    _create: function () {
        this._initContent();
    },

    /**
     * Update sidebar block.
     */
    update: function () {
        $(this.options.targetElement).trigger('contentUpdated');
        this._calcHeight();
        this._isOverflowed();
    },

    /**
     * @private
     */
    _initContent: function () {
        var self = this,
            events = {};

        this.element.decorate('list', this.options.isRecursive);

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + this.options.button.close] = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(self.options.targetElement).dropdownDialog('close');
        };
        events['click ' + this.options.button.checkout] = $.proxy(function () {
            var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
                customer = customerData.get('customer'),
                element = $(this.options.button.checkout);

            if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
                // set URL for redirect on successful login/registration. It's postprocessed on backend.
                $.cookie('login_redirect', this.options.url.checkout);

                if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
                    element.prop('disabled', true);
                    location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
                } else {
                    authenticationPopup.showModal();
                }

                return false;
            }
            element.prop('disabled', true);
            location.href = this.options.url.checkout;
        }, this);

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {

            event.stopPropagation();

            confirm({

                content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                actions: {
                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    confirm: function () {

        self._removeItemCategory($(event.currentTarget));
                       self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));                                                        
                       // location.reload();

                    },


                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    always: function (e) {
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['keyup ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
            self._showItemButton($(event.target));
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['change ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
            self._showItemButton($(event.target));
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + this.options.item.button] = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            self._updateItemQty($(event.currentTarget));
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['focusout ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
            self._validateQty($(event.currentTarget));
        };

        this._on(this.element, events);
        this._calcHeight();
        this._isOverflowed();
    },

    /**
     * Add 'overflowed' class to minicart items wrapper element
     *
     * @private
     */
    _isOverflowed: function () {
        var list = $(this.options.minicart.list),
            cssOverflowClass = 'overflowed';

        if (this.scrollHeight > list.innerHeight()) {
            list.parent().addClass(cssOverflowClass);
        } else {
            list.parent().removeClass(cssOverflowClass);
        }
    },

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _showItemButton: function (elem) {
        var itemId = elem.data('cart-item'),
            itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

        if (this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
            $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).show('fade', 300);
        } else if (elem.val() == 0) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            this._hideItemButton(elem);
        } else {
            this._hideItemButton(elem);
        }
    },

    /**
     * @param {*} origin - origin qty. 'data-item-qty' attribute.
     * @param {*} changed - new qty.
     * @returns {Boolean}
     * @private
     */
    _isValidQty: function (origin, changed) {
        return origin != changed && //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            changed.length > 0 &&
            changed - 0 == changed && //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            changed - 0 > 0;
    },

    /**
     * @param {Object} elem
     * @private
     */
    _validateQty: function (elem) {
        var itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

        if (!this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
            elem.val(itemQty);
        }
    },

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _hideItemButton: function (elem) {
        var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

        $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).hide('fade', 300);
    },

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _updateItemQty: function (elem) {
        var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

        this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
            'item_id': itemId,
            'item_qty': $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val()
        }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
    },

    /**
     * Update content after update qty
     *
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     */
    _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
        var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

        if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
            $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty');

            if (window.location.href === this.shoppingCartUrl) {
                window.location.reload(false);
            }
        }
        this._hideItemButton(elem);
    },

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _removeItem: function (elem) {
        console.log(this.options.url.remove);
        var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

        this._ajax(this.options.url.remove, {
            'item_id': itemId
        }, elem, this._removeItemAfter);
    },

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _removeItemCategory: function (elem) {

       // var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');
        var skuId = elem.data('cart-item');

        var customUrl = window.customUrl;
        console.log(customUrl); 

        this._ajaxnew(customUrl, {
            'sku': skuId
        }, elem);

        //$('.subCategoryCountInCart').css("display", "none");
    },

    /**
     * Update content after item remove
     *
     * @param {Object} elem
     * @private
     */
    _removeItemAfter: function (elem) {
        var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

        if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
            $(document).trigger('ajax:removeFromCart', {
                productIds: [productData['product_id']]
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * Retrieves product data by Id.
     *
     * @param {Number} productId - product Id
     * @returns {Object|undefined}
     * @private
     */
    _getProductById: function (productId) {
        return _.find(customerData.get('cart')().items, function (item) {
            return productId === Number(item['item_id']);
        });
    },

    /**
     * @param {String} url - ajax url
     * @param {Object} data - post data for ajax call
     * @param {Object} elem - element that initiated the event
     * @param {Function} callback - callback method to execute after AJAX success
     */
    _ajax: function (url, data, elem, callback) {
        $.extend(data, {
            'form_key': $.mage.cookies.get('form_key')
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
            //showLoader: true,

            /** @inheritdoc */
            beforeSend: function () {
                elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            complete: function () {
                elem.attr('disabled', null);
            }

        })

            .done(function (response) {
                var msg;

                if (response.success) {
                    callback.call(this, elem, response);
                } else {
                    msg = response['error_message'];

                    if (msg) {
                        alert({
                            content: msg
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    },


    _ajaxnew: function (url, data, elem) {
        console.log(elem);
                   //var itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');
                    //console.log(itemQty);
                    //console.log($('#cart-item-' + elem + '-qty').val())
        $.extend(data, {
            'form_key': $.mage.cookies.get('form_key')
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
           // showLoader: true,

            /** @inheritdoc */
            beforeSend: function () {
                elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            complete: function () {
                elem.attr('disabled', null);
            }

        })

            .done(function (response) {

                if(response.cat_id){

                   var bagcount =  parseInt($("#"+ response.cat_id + " strong").text());
                   var updatedBagcount = bagcount - response.qty;
                   if(updatedBagcount <= 0){
                       $("span#"+ response.cat_id).hide();
                   } else {
                       $("#"+ response.cat_id + " strong").html(updatedBagcount);
                   }
                }
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    },


    /**
     * Calculate height of minicart list
     *
     * @private
     */
    _calcHeight: function () {
        var self = this,
            height = 0,
            counter = this.options.minicart.maxItemsVisible,
            target = $(this.options.minicart.list),
            outerHeight;

        self.scrollHeight = 0;
        target.children().each(function () {

            if ($(this).find('.options').length > 0) {
                $(this).collapsible();
            }
            outerHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

            if (counter-- > 0) {
                height += outerHeight;
            }
            self.scrollHeight += outerHeight;
        });

        target.parent().height(height);
    }


});

return $.mage.sidebar;
  });
```

after thai in controller:

```
public function execute()
{
    $itemid = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');

    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productData = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($itemid);
    $productId = $productData['product_id'];
    $qty = $productData['qty'];
    print_r($productId); 
    $product = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        $categoriesId = $product->getCategoryIds();
        print_r($categoriesId); 
        foreach($categoriesId as $categoryId){
           $cat = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);


        }
```

**Through this call, some time i am getting product id sometime not. can anyone please help me how to get product id through item id , everytime, and what i am doing wrong?**

Comment: Does `item_id` sending all the time to your custom controller?

Comment: yes.. item id i am getting all the time.

Comment: You can send item_sku instead of item id to controller and load product by sku.

Comment: i did, but still same thing happen

Comment: Can you pls share your whole `sidebar.js` code to find another solution?

Comment: please check my sidebar.js updated  code, in which  _"removeItemCategory: function (elem)  " i created to call controller. and action is in "_ajaxnew: function (url, data, elem)" .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101623/discussion-between-ranganathan-and-sam).

Answer (score 0):

You can get SKU from item, then can load produdct by SKU and then can get the product details

Refer: [How to load product by SKU in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111245/how-to-load-product-by-sku-in-magento-2)

Item ID is often different from product ID

Comment: i tried with this  and getting the error like" Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getProductFromLocalCache() must be of the type string, null given,"

Comment: it seems to be some issue with cache. so, please clear cache once and if possible, run setup:di:compile too

Comment: yes, i tried with sku, but again same issue, some time , we get the sku value, some time not

Comment: well, that' seems impossible, becuase a product/item will definetly have an SKU

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code to get category object from product sku

```
protected $_cart;
protected $_productRepository;
protected $_categoryRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
) {
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $itemId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');
    $quoteItem = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
    $product = $this->_productRepository->get($quoteItem->getProductSku());
    $categoriesId = $product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach($categoriesId as $categoryId){
        $cat = $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    } 
}
```

**Note:** Do not use objectmanager directly, It is not a good practice.