# get product Id using product SKU

Tags: magento2, sku, id

I am trying to get the product Id but below are given the conditions through which I want to get Id of the product.
I have SKU of the product. but using that sku I want to get Id of that product.
It is necessary condition to get product Id using SKU no other way I want....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the product factory as explained [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/111247/35330), then just use the `$product->getIdBySku($sku)` method.

Comment: thank you Diana Botean..Your quick response save my time a lot.

Comment: you're most welcome!